# function calling another function. colorsys

Tags: python, function

newbie here,
Python has a function called colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(r, g, b) and works as below:

```
import colorsys
colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(0.2, 0.4, 0.4) #Takes 3 argument as Red Green Blue
```

result: (0.5, 0.5, 0.4) #convert Red Green Blue to hue, saturation, lightness

i am trying to write a function that calls this function!here is my code

```
import colorsys
def convert(r,g,b):
    colorsys.rgb_to_hsv() #also tried colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(r,g,b)
print(convert(0.2, 0.4, 0.4))
```

TypeError: rgb_to_hsv() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'r', 'g', and 'b'

Comment: You take the arguments in convert(r, g, b). You need to pass them to colosrsys.rgb_to_hsv() like this. colorsys.rgb_to_hsb(r, g, b)

Comment: Are you sure you closed the parenthesis in `print(convert(0.2, 0.4, 0.4)`? Or is it just a typo here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you tried this option but it seems to work for me. You were not returning the value from convert function and did not have an extra parenthesis at the end of the code.

```
import colorsys
def convert(r,g,b):
    return colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(r, g, b) #also tried colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(r,g,b)
print(convert(0.2, 0.4, 0.4))
```